# fontawesome links not working in my sticky footer in Safari

Tags: safari, sticky-footer, font-awesome

My sticky footer with my fontawesome icons is displaying perfectly in all browsers, but in Safari, the links aren't working.

Here is my code:

```
<style>

h4 {
     font-size: 1em;
     color: #A0A0A0;
     bottom: 15px;
     position: relative;
     letter-spacing: 10px;
}

.footer{
    position: fixed;
    left:0px;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0px;
    height: 20px;
    background: #404040;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
    opacity:0.95;
}

</style>

......

<div class="footer">
    <h4> 
    <a href="https://twitter.com/">
        <i class="icon-twitter icon-2x"></i> </a>
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/">
        <i class="icon-facebook icon-2x"></i></a>
    <a href="http://wordpress.com/">
        <i class="icon-rss icon-2x"></i></a>
    </h4>
 </div>
```

Can anyone tell me why this doesn't work in safari? And how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

I just into this problem. I believe this is caused by safari giving the target no dimensions (i.e. 0px x 0px). If you force inline-block on the `<i>` element it should to work correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem.

I added to the icon's class

> display:inline-block;

and it worked fine!